# How can the little l2 topology be finer than the uniform topology?

Tags: general-topology

How can the $\ell_2$ topology be finer than the uniform topology on the set $X$ of square-summable sequences?

If the  $\ell_2$ metric is always greater than or equal to the uniform metric. Wouldn't this mean that the epsilon balls in  $\ell_2$ are always bigger than the epsilon balls under the uniform metric? I'm trying to show that the  $\ell_2$ balls are contained inside the uniform balls, right?

Comment: It seems to me that epsilon balls in $\ell_2$ are actually smaller because $\ell_2$ metric is greater.

Comment: Can you explain to me why the balls in a metric that is greater would be smaller?

Comment: Because a ball is defined by fixing an upper bound on the distance from a fixed point.
Anyway, the inequality of the metrics does not imply that the topologies are different.

Comment: Okay I think I understand now. We have a fixed epsilon defining our balls so the larger the metric, the less points that can be contained inside the ball. So the epsilon balls of l2 are smaller than the epsilon balls of the uniform metric. Then since we can fit an epsilon ball from the l2 metric inside any uniform metric ball we can conclude that the l2 topology is finer than the uniform topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to show that

1. Every open uniform ball contains an $\ell_2$ ball.
2. There exists an open uniform ball that is not contained in any $\ell_2$ balls.

By knowing that the $\ell_2$ metric is greater than or equal to the uniform metric, you only prove 1.

To prove 2,
suppose $B$ is an open ball of radius $\sqrt{r/2}$ with respect to the uniform metric centered at $0$. $B$ consists  of sequences $(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 < \infty$ and $|x_n| < r$. It is easy to see that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2$ is not bounded even when $x_n$ are all bounded by $r$, so $B$ is not contained in any $\ell_2$ balls. (More rigorously, for any given $L > 0$, there exists an integer $m$ such that $mr/2 > L$. The sequence defined by $x_n = \sqrt{r/2}$ for $n \le m$ and $x_n = 0$ for $n > m$ is a member of $B$, but not a member of an $\ell_2$ ball of radius $L$ because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 = \sum_{n=1}^m (r/2) = mr/2 > L$. Therefore, $B$ is not contained in $\ell_2$ balls of any radii.)

Comment: If I'm only trying to prove finer, not strictly finer then don't I only need to show 1?

Comment: Oh. I guess the terminology wasn't clear to me then. In that case, you only need $1$, not $2$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a misleading concept. Consider, for example, the real line. If you define the $\epsilon$-ball to be $B(x,\epsilon)=\{(y\space s.t.\space 2|y-x|<\epsilon\}$ this would make balls "2 times smaller", yet the topology is the same.

Remember, that even if for a fixed $\epsilon$ $d_1$-$\epsilon$-ball is smaller than the $d_2$-$\epsilon$-ball, there may still be a smaller $\delta$ such that $d_2$-$\delta$-ball is smaller than $d_1$-$\epsilon$-ball.

Now **hint**: to show that $\ell_2$ is finer than the uniform but coarser than the box topology consider $M(x)=\{y:|x_i-y_i|^2<\epsilon^2/2^i\}$ and show that $M(x)\subset B_{\ell_2}(x,\epsilon)\subset B_{\rho}(x,\epsilon)$ where $\rho$ is uniform metric.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to show that y in M(x) also converge? How would you show that?