# $(a)$ Show that on $X$, we have the inclusions $ \mbox{ box topology } \ \supset \ \ell^2 \mbox{ topology } \ \supset \ \mbox{ uniform topology}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ consisting of all sequences $x$ such that $\sum x_i^2$ converges. Then the formula $$d(x,y) = \left[ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left( x_i - y_i \right)^2 \right]^{\frac{1}{2}} $$ defines a metric on $X$. On $X$ we have the three topologies it inherits from the box, uniform, and product topologies on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. We have also the topology given by the metric $d$, which we call the $\ell^2$ topology.

> (a) Show that on $X$, we have the inclusions $$ \mbox{ box topology } \ \supset \ \ell^2 \mbox{ topology } \ \supset \ \mbox{ uniform topology}.$$

as  i got answer  here [How can the little l2 topology be finer than the uniform topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672939/how-can-the-little-l2-topology-be-finer-than-the-uniform-topology)

But  i didn't understand  this...[image]

Pliz  give  me the proper  solution  so that  i can  easily understands....

Comment: Just compute. Take the sequence they gave you, $x=(\sqrt{r/2},\sqrt{r/2},...,\sqrt{r/2},0,0,...)$, where there are $m$ non-zero terns at the beginning of it. Then $\sup_n|x_n|=\sqrt{r/2}$. I guess they are taking $r$ such that $\sqrt{r/2}\leq r$. So, that means that $x$ is in the ball of radius $r$ for the uniform metric. On the other hand, $\|x\|_2=\sum_{n=1}^{m}(\sqrt{r/2})^2=rm/2$. But since $m$ is arbitrary, we can put it as large as we want. Therefore, $\|x\|_2$ can be very large, hence outside of any ball of $\|\cdot\|_2$ that we fix beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we have two topologies $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$ on $X$ (with local neighbourhood bases $\mathcal{N}_1(x), \mathcal{N}_2(x)$ resp., then $\mathcal{T}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{T}_2$ iff for every $x \in X$ and every $O \in \mathcal{N}_1(x)$ there is some $O' \in \mathcal{N}_2(x)$ with $O' \subseteq O$.

This is quite clear from the definitions. It might be a lemma in your text, or easily provable yourself.

With the $d$-metric (the $\ell_2$-metric) and the uniform metric $d_u$ we have such a situation: If $x \in X$ and $r>0$ (we can assume $r<1$ wlog, as such balls form a local base anyway) we have $B_d(x,\frac{r^2}{4}) \subseteq B_{d_u}(x,r)$. This implies that $\mathcal{T}_u \subseteq \mathcal{T}_d$, as required.

Also, if we have an open ball $B_d(x,r)$ in the $\ell_2$-metric, we can define the basic box-open set $U(x) = \prod_n (x_n - \frac{r^2}{2^n}, x + \frac{r^2}{2^n})$ and prove that $U(x) \subseteq B_d(x,r)$, showing $\mathcal{T}_d \subseteq \mathcal{T}_{\text{box}}$

E.g. define the sequence in $X$:

$x_1 = (1,0,0,0,\ldots)$

$x_2 = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0, \ldots,)$

$\ldots$

$x_n = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, \ldots, \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} (n \text{ terms })\,, 0,0 \ldots,)$

which converges to $(0,0,0,\ldots)$ in the uniform metric (and product topology too), but not in the $d$-metric (where the distance to that point from each $x_n$ is $1$).

On the other hand, it's also easy to find convergent sequences under $d$ that are not box-convergent. Such sequences show the properness of the inclusions.

Comment: @ henno sir   as im  not getting  ur last second line....but not in the $d$-metric (where the distance to that point from each $x_n$ is $1$),,,,,,,my  thinking  is that $d(x_n,0) = \frac {1}{\sqrt n}$  how  it is  1

Comment: To the proposer.  With $u_i=1/\sqrt n\;$  for $1\leq i\leq n, $ and $u_i=0$  for $i>n$ and for $v_i=0$ for all $i$ we have $d(x_n,0)^2=d(u,v)^2=\sum_{i\in \Bbb N}(u_i-v_i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(1/n)=1.$...Perhaps you forgot that $d$ is not the uniform metric.

Comment: @lomber see the other comment. The $d$-metric is a sum of squares.

Comment: thanks  a  lots   @HennoBrandsma sir

Comment: thanks @ Danielwainfleet